# Creating Custom Calendar with Jambi

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi, jambi

When making customize calendar, how can I set a date and get the total days of that month? Or even get the week day of that specific date?
Like **April** is **30 Days**, **May** is **31 days**, **February** every **4 years** is **29 days** and week days are different every year.

I'm using Jambi (Qt 4.7 in java) and I want to make calendar with few `QComboBox`, and I use `QDate` to get the current date like so:

```
//return current year
QDate.currentDate().year();

//return total days in current month
QDate.currentDate().daysInMonth();

//return current month
QDate.currentDate().month();

//return current day in month
QDate.currentDate().day();

//return current day in week
QDate.currentDate().dayOfWeek();
```

The thing is that what I'm getting is **current** information.

1. How can I ask like in year **2020**, month **February**, how many **days** are in there?
2. And **10th**, **February**, **2020** is which day in **week**?

I looked into **[QData documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html)**, I couldn't find any option to set date so i can get info from it, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#QDate-2) to pass the date you want?

For example:

```
QDate date = new QDate(202, 2, 1);
date.daysInMonth();
```

Comment: thanks, Yeah that's work, also what about second question, "which day in week"? like is it Monday or ...?

Comment: oh, you meant `QDate` right? i thought you are talking about java built in `Date`, yeah if i use `QDate` it will work perfectly, also since everything is String i can just use `QDate second_date = QDate.fromString("1022020", "dMyyyy");` so i don't need to convert them to Integer.

Comment: Yes, I meant `QDate`. Fixed the answer. For getting week day number of the day, you can just look last thing in your answer ;) (spoiler: `daysOfWeek()`). `currentDate()` just constructs the object for you, you can always do it manually too. The doc should tell everything you need.